# No meetings scheduled today vs No meetings scheduled for today. What is the difference?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, differences, sentence

No meetings scheduled today vs No meetings scheduled for today. When we want to specify that the statement which is talking meetings about to happen that day. Which one to use?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

***No meetings scheduled today*** means you have not created any meeting today may it be for today it self or any other day.

***No meetings scheduled for today*** means you have not created any meeting previously or today which was going to take place today(Now).

So the statement which talks about the meeting about to happen today is :

> No meetings scheduled for today

Comment: Both are seen used interchangeably, but the first may mean "scheduling hasn't happened today - for today or some other day", whereas '...for today' refers to the meetings that should happen today.